# how to send verification mail in firebase and forgot password link in firebase flutter version

Tags: dart, firebase-authentication, flutter

how to send verification mail in firebase and forgot password link in firebase flutter version

firebase_auth plugin I don't found any forgot password method is there any other way for both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [current master](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/lib/firebase_auth.dart), I don't think it is implemented yet. Perhaps file a feature request in [flutter issue tracker](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues)?

Answer (score 9):

fire base is providing the option to reset the password of the user 
this query will send a url for reseting the password to user mail id

```
var auth = firebase.auth();
var emailAddress = "<Mail_id >";

auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(emailAddress).then(function() {
  // Email sent.
    console.log("welcome")
}).catch(function(error) {
  // An error happened.
});
```

Answer (score 6):

The method is available in the `FirebaseUser`, not `FirebaseAuth` (_auth).

```
await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
  email: _userEmail,
  password: _userPassword
).then((FirebaseUser user) {
  // upon success, send email verification
  user.sendEmailVerification();  
  ...
})
.catchError(...);
```