# How do I Check if an email address is real or fake in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I use `createUserWithEmailAndPassword(string, string)` in flutter, but I noticed if the user used a fake email address, like making us some random Gmail or yahoo account that doesn't exist, the user would still be registered, is there a solution to this

Or some logic that checks if the email account is real, then I can use the result in an if else statement to create the account

Comment: Good luck ;) in general, that's why everyone sends confirmation mails

Comment: Hi SeqTop.  The only 100% way to verify an email address exists is to send an email to it.   That's why some sites when you register will send you a verification link to click.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can check email is exist or not, I mean email is real that is somebody have in firebase android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48814916/how-can-check-email-is-exist-or-not-i-mean-email-is-real-that-is-somebody-have)

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to do this in firebase Auth in flutter,.  To send the verification email and check if user is verified

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a solution that doesn't involve blocking the user experience, you'll be disappointed. We could come up with a new solution for checking whether an email exists or not, but this doesn't guarantee you anything. The user may use an existing email that doesn't belong to him/her.

The best you can do is send a verification email to your user, which is supported by Firebase. However, the user experience is going to be blocked until the user verifies the email.

#### Update

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51412379/6696558) how to send the user the verification email and [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20390#issuecomment-415395616) how to see if the email has been verified.

Comment: I guess I would have to go with this then,  where can I find the implementation of sending the verification email address and checking if the user is verified  when next he logs in, thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Sure, how then do I check when next he logs in if his/her email is verified

Comment: The second link (to Github) shows how. Just use `user.isEmailVerified`.